# Good practice parsing specific html table with urls in perl

Tags: perl, html-table, html-parsing

Given a html with table data like the following...

```
<tr class=nbg1><td><A HREF=api.dll?pgm=cdq32&p1=oavmsd&p2=fg3m9s5d&p3=&cmd=w1d27d0id9654&hl=antibio&lstid=026>Nadifloxacin</A></td><td>Aknetherapeutikum Antibiotikum (Gyrasehemmer)</td><td>WST</td><td></td></tr>
<tr class=nbg2><td><A HREF=api.dll?pgm=cdq32&p1=oavmsd&p2=fg3m9s5d&p3=&cmd=w1d27d0id9728&hl=antibio&lstid=026>Ertapenem</A></td><td>Antibiotikum</td><td>WST</td><td></td></tr>
<tr class=nbg1><td><A HREF=api.dll?pgm=cdq32&p1=oavmsd&p2=fg3m9s5d&p3=&cmd=w1d27d0id9761&hl=antibio&lstid=026>Panipenem</A></td><td>Beta-Lactam-Antibiotikum</td><td>WST</td><td></td></tr>
<tr class=nbg2><td><A HREF=api.dll?pgm=cdq32&p1=oavmsd&p2=fg3m9s5d&p3=&cmd=w1d27d0id10302&hl=antibio&lstid=026>Prulifloxacin</A></td><td>Antibiotikum (Gyrasehemmer)</td><td>WST</td><td></td></tr>
</table></td>
<td width=15></td><td valign=top nowrap class=NBG1>
<TABLE width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<TR><TD CLASS="NBG2">
</TD></TR></TABLE><BR>
```

I need to parse the url and the url description, where the extracted url will be used for further parsing the subpage. What would be a good practice to accomplish this, especially getting the url.

current code:

```
my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( depth => 3, count => 0 ); 
$te->parse($mainpage); 
my $ts = ""; 
my $row = ""; 
foreach $ts ($te->tables) { 
   foreach $row ($ts->rows) { 
      print @$row[0] . "\n"; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract only the href attribute from each a' element in that table, no need to use TableExtract, just use `HTML::Query`

```
my $qry = HTML::Query->new(text => $mainpage);


my @hrefs = map { $_->attr('href') } grep { m/api\.dll/i } $qry->query('tr > td > a')->get_elements();
```

no tested, but you get the idea...

Comment: sure, but HTML::Query is not available in the default repo of Debian 5, and it would be another module (overhead). Isn't there a one module for all solution? Just need the url and the url description.

Comment: why do you need defauly repo? I'm sure its not available on ubuntu repo as well, just use CPAN to install modules, or cpanm.

Comment: P.S: about module overhead, Perl is all about CPAN, thats its key of strength (among other stuff, but thats the main one). if you dont want to use module, use global match (m//g) regex to match all the urls and their description, since I seems like all these urls have the same format.

Comment: HTML::Query looks very specific for me

Answer (score -1):

[HTML::TableExtract](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTableExtract) can help you exactly with dealing with tables.

Comment: I need to put "api.dll?pgm=cdq32&p1=oavmsd&p2=fg3m..." into a variable